# How to use ZwQueryInformationProcess to get ProcessImageFileName in a kernel driver?

Tags: c++, hook, driver, wdk

I'm writing a simple kernel driver for my application (think of a very simple anti-malware application.)

I've hooked `ZwOpenFile()` and used `PsGetCurrentProcess()` to get a handle to the caller process.

It returns a PEPROCESS structure:

```
PEPROCESS proc = PsGetCurrentProcess();
```

I'm using `ZwQueryInformationProcess()` to get the `PID` and `ImageFileName`:

```
DbgPrint("ZwOpenFile Called...\n");
DbgPrint("PID: %d\n", PsGetProcessId(proc));
DbgPrint("ImageFileName: %.16s\n", PsGetProcessImageFileName(proc));
```

and trying to get the process `FullPath` this way (but I get BSOD):

```
WCHAR strBuffer[260];
UNICODE_STRING str;

//initialize
str.Buffer = strBuffer;
str.Length = 0x0;
str.MaximumLength = sizeof(strBuffer);

//note that the seconds arg (27) is ProcessImageFileName
ZwQueryInformationProcess(proc, 27, &str, sizeof(str), NULL);

DbgPrint("FullPath: %wZ\n", str.Buffer);
```

[image: DbgView Output]

As you see `str.Buffer` is empty or filled with garbage. Perhaps a buffer overflow while filling the `str` via `ZwQueryInformationProcess()` triggers the BSOD.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MSDN docs for this API indicate that

> When the ProcessInformationClass
>   parameter is ProcessImageFileName, the
>   buffer pointed to by the
>   ProcessInformation parameter should be
>   large enough to hold a UNICODE_STRING
>   structure as well as the string
>   itself. The string stored in the
>   Buffer member is the name of the image
>   file.file.

With this in mind, I suggest you try modifying your buffer structure like this:

```
WCHAR strBuffer[(sizeof(UNICODE_STRING) / sizeof(WCHAR)) + 260];
UNICODE_STRING str;
str = (UNICODE_STRING*)&strBuffer;

//initialize
str.Buffer = &strBuffer[sizeof(UNICODE_STRING) / sizeof(WCHAR)];
str.Length = 0x0;
str.MaximumLength = 260 * sizeof(WCHAR);

//note that the seconds arg (27) is ProcessImageFileName
ZwQueryInformationProcess(proc, 27, &strBuffer, sizeof(strBuffer), NULL);
```

Additionally, your code needs to check and handle the error case described in the docs here.  This may be why you missed the BSOD trigger case.

> If the buffer is too small, the
>   function fails with the
>   STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH error code
>   and the ReturnLength parameter is set
>   to the required buffer size.

Comment: where is `UNICODE_STRING str;` used here?

Comment: @Konrad it's used implicitly thru `strBuffer`

Answer (score 5):

//Declare this piece of code in header file if available otherwise before the Function definition..

```
typedef NTSTATUS (*QUERY_INFO_PROCESS) (
__in HANDLE ProcessHandle,
__in PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
__out_bcount(ProcessInformationLength) PVOID ProcessInformation,
__in ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
__out_opt PULONG ReturnLength
);

QUERY_INFO_PROCESS ZwQueryInformationProcess;
```

//Function Definition

```
NTSTATUS GetProcessImageName(HANDLE processId, PUNICODE_STRING ProcessImageName)
{
NTSTATUS status;
ULONG returnedLength;
ULONG bufferLength;
HANDLE hProcess;
PVOID buffer;
PEPROCESS eProcess;
PUNICODE_STRING imageName;

PAGED_CODE(); // this eliminates the possibility of the IDLE Thread/Process

status = PsLookupProcessByProcessId(processId, &eProcess);

if(NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    status = ObOpenObjectByPointer(eProcess,0, NULL, 0,0,KernelMode,&hProcess);
    if(NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
    } else {
        DbgPrint("ObOpenObjectByPointer Failed: %08x\n", status);
    }
    ObDereferenceObject(eProcess);
} else {
    DbgPrint("PsLookupProcessByProcessId Failed: %08x\n", status);
}


if (NULL == ZwQueryInformationProcess) {

    UNICODE_STRING routineName;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&routineName, L"ZwQueryInformationProcess");

    ZwQueryInformationProcess =
           (QUERY_INFO_PROCESS) MmGetSystemRoutineAddress(&routineName);

    if (NULL == ZwQueryInformationProcess) {
        DbgPrint("Cannot resolve ZwQueryInformationProcess\n");
    }
}

/* Query the actual size of the process path */
status = ZwQueryInformationProcess( hProcess,
                                    ProcessImageFileName,
                                    NULL, // buffer
                                    0, // buffer size
                                    &returnedLength);

if (STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH != status) {
    return status;
}

/* Check there is enough space to store the actual process
   path when it is found. If not return an error with the
   required size */
bufferLength = returnedLength - sizeof(UNICODE_STRING);
if (ProcessImageName->MaximumLength < bufferLength)
{
    ProcessImageName->MaximumLength = (USHORT) bufferLength;
    return STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW;   
}

/* Allocate a temporary buffer to store the path name */
buffer = ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, returnedLength, 'uLT1');

if (NULL == buffer) 
{
    return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;   
}

/* Retrieve the process path from the handle to the process */
status = ZwQueryInformationProcess( hProcess,
                                    ProcessImageFileName,
                                    buffer,
                                    returnedLength,
                                    &returnedLength);

if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) 
{
    /* Copy the path name */
    imageName = (PUNICODE_STRING) buffer;
    RtlCopyUnicodeString(ProcessImageName, imageName);
}

/* Free the temp buffer which stored the path */
ExFreePoolWithTag(buffer, 'uLT1');

return status;
}
```

//Function Call.. Write this piece of code in PreOperation Call back  and IRQ should be PASSIVE_LEVEL

```
PEPROCESS objCurProcess=NULL;
HANDLE hProcess;
UNICODE_STRING fullPath;

objCurProcess=IoThreadToProcess(Data->Thread);//Note: Date is type of FLT_CALLBACK_DATA which is in PreOperation Callback as argument

hProcess=PsGetProcessID(objCurProcess);

fullPath.Length=0;
fullPath.MaximumLength=520;
fullPath.Buffer=(PWSTR)ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool,520,'uUT1');

GetProcessImageName(hProcess,&fullPath);
```

in fullPath variable there is Full Path of Process .. Like if the process is explorer.exe then path will be look like this:-

```
\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\explorer.exe
```

Note:- \Device\HarddiskVolume3 Path might be changed due to Machine and different volume in hard disk this is an example in my case.

Answer (score 0):

`ZwQueryInformationProcess` needs a `HANDLE`, not a `PROCESS`!
You need to use `ObOpenObjectByPointer` to get the handle first.