# error when try convert for UNICODE_STRING * To UNICODE_STRING

Tags: device-driver, wdk, wdm

i am trying to write simple driver for get full path of Image when Process executed
based on [Steve Townsend Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3709916/1275574) i write below code for my `ProcessCallback` that call from `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine` in `DriverEntry` of my driver:

```
void ProcessCallback(
    IN HANDLE  hParentId, 
    IN HANDLE  hProcessId, 
    IN BOOLEAN bCreate
    )

{
    if(bCreate)
    {
        PEPROCESS proc = PsGetCurrentProcess();

        WCHAR  strBuffer[(sizeof(UNICODE_STRING) / sizeof(WCHAR)) + 260];
        UNICODE_STRING str;
        str =(UNICODE_STRING*)&strBuffer;

        //initialize
        str.Buffer = &strBuffer[sizeof(UNICODE_STRING) / sizeof(WCHAR)];
        str.Length = 0x0;
        str.MaximumLength = 260 * sizeof(WCHAR);

        //note that the seconds arg (27) is ProcessImageFileName
        ZwQueryInformationProcess(proc, 27, &strBuffer, sizeof(strBuffer), NULL);

        DbgPrint("Start @  %wZ\n", str.Buffer); 

    }
    else
        DbgPrint("PID %i Terminated",hProcessId );

}
```

but when i try to build my code i get below error for  `str =(UNICODE_STRING*)&strBuffer;`
:

> error cannot convert for UNICODE_STRING * To  UNICODE_STRING

what's wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change UNICODE_STRING str to UNICODE_STRING *str that should work. Then pass str to the ZwQueryInformationProcess